# NullpointerException in restartLoader

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on my Android app and I've got one Activity showing a list of items, and then another activity for editing a particular item. But now I get a NullpointerException in restartLoader() when returning from editing an item.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
```

I assume the who in ResultInfo shouldn't be null, but that's just a guess.

```
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {duttsoft.travel/duttsoft.travel.TravelHealthActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.restartLoader(LoaderManager.java:651)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at duttsoft.travel.TravelHealthActivity.onActivityResult(TravelHealthActivity.java:136)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
08-10 00:44:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
```

I'm drawing a blank why I get this exception and how to fix it, any ideas?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is on this line:

```
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

You're passing `null` as a parameter, and then getting an NPE. Try passing an empty Bundle object instead.

Comment: Use logging and breakpoints to see which of your objects are null on execution

Comment: Bundle is ignored if null is given as parameter. No link withe the NPE at all.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem. My problem was that when I initially init-ed the loader I had returned null as the Loader in the onCreateLoader callback method. When I fixed that my crash stopped appearing. Even though the question is almost a year old I figured I'd leave this answer here if anyone would stumble upon the same problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot hordurh! This was exactly what I was doing. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Correct answer here! But I need to return an empty cursorloader: how can I do that?

Comment: Yes! It is because createLoader returns null! You can't find it by the stacktrace.